# How can I tell the difference between a pregnant or overweight cat?

Tags: cats, breeding, weight, pregnancy

I'm taking care of this cat, and I don't have a great deal of experience with animals. My friend told me the cat was overweight when we first got her, but I've noticed she has quite a pronounced belly as well.

Does this cat look pregnant, or is she simply overweight?

https://streamable.com/zldc

Comment: So are you going to tell us the outcome?

Comment: @keshlam Pretty sure she's just overweight since we've had her nearing 64 days and it's not obvious she's pregnant yet. Could be a hormone imbalance like you said, maybe I'm just paranoid though.

Comment: She should be visiting a vet once a year anyway; if you are still nervous, you could move that date up and take her in now without significantly affecting the care budget in the long term. Sometimes a trip to the vet is justified even if it's just to calm the human.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average cat's gestation period is 64 days. How long has this been an issue, and how rapidly has it been changing?

If in doubt, you should get the cat to a vet for a checkup. The cat might be pregnant, fat, or sick, and a vet can determine which and what should be done about it if anything.

"You might notice subtle indications of pregnancy after the first 3 weeks. The cat's nipples will begin to swell and their color will change from white to a rosy pink."

I can't tell from the video.

Comment: We've had her a little under a month and I've only noticed this in the past week. She's also an indoor cat, so she hasn't had the opportunity to mate with anyone in that time. Would she be bigger she was actually pregnant from before we got her?

Comment: She 100% has pink nipples, and I've never noticed them before.

Comment: That does suggest pregnancy, though it could just be a hormonal imbalance ("false pregnancy").